# recyclerView setAdapter is very slow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used recyclerView in my android app and filled it by a list with 120 items. my problem is that it takes a couple of time to load recyclerView. it seems that `setAdapter()` method is very slow . what can I do to fix it?

```
list.addAll(db.getKarevanMembers());
KarevanMembersAdapter adapter = new KarevanMembersAdapter(list);
binding.membersLayout.karevanMembersList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Better to see Adapter and ViewHolder code. Also, Android Profiler will help you to identify worthiest methods.

Comment: please post your code of KarevanMembersAdapter adapter

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting new adapter change data of current adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

If you want to change/remove only some elements in the list, use the methods `notifyItemInserted, notifyItemRangeInserted, notifyItemChanged, notifyItemRangeChanged, notifyItemRangeRemoved, notifyItemRemoved` to update adapter (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html).

Comment: try this but not working. loading list is still too slow

Comment: I really don't get who and why down voted this answer. Each question about changing data for RV on runtime is done this way.

Comment: If that's slow too, then probably you have heavy code in `onBindViewHolder` method.